# Printf'ing floating point numbers in C++ gives zeroes

Tags: c++, printf

I am doing some c++ right now and stumbled on a problem I can't get to wrap my head around.

I am doing a floating point comparison like this:

```
if(dists.at<float>(i,0) <= 0.80 * dists.at<float>(i,1)) {
  matched = true;
  matches++;
} else {
  printf((dists.at<float>(i,0) <= 0.80 * dists.at<float>(i,1)) ? "true\n" : "false");
  printf("threw one away because of dist: %f/%f\n", dists.at<float>(i,0),dists.at<float>(i,1));
}
```

at the first line, the comparison threw a false what means: dists[0] > dists[1]
When we print the values, the results are this:

```
falsethrew one away because of dist: 0.000000/0.000000
falsethrew one away because of dist: 0.000000/0.000000
```

I think it has something to do with the results not being a float or something, but I'm no pro at C++ so I could use some help to find out what these values are.

Comment: Not enough digits printed? `float` provides up to 7 digits of precision.

Comment: Nup, dist: %1.7f/%1.7f\n gives the same results:

Comment: %g instead of %f can print very small floating point numbers if it is the problem.

Comment: Or `%e` for scientific notation.

Comment: Ahh that was the problem, it was indeed a very very small number hehe. thanks for the help. %g worked

Comment: @Keugyeol: kindly post your comment as answer for the community

Comment: "7 digits of precision" doesn't mean "to 0.0000001", it means having 7 significant figures (in decimal). `FLOAT_MIN` is something around 1E-37.

Comment: Set a breakpoint, assign the float to a variable (`auto tmp = dists.at<float>(i,0);`), and see if `tmp` is really 0, or even really a float, in your debugger.

Comment: What does `dists.at<float>` evaluate to? What type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was due to the number being too small.

In response to @NirMH, I am posting my comment as an answer.

`%g` instead of `%f` can print very small floating point numbers.

There are other options such as `%e`, as @ilent2 mentioned in the comment.

For example:

```
double num = 1.0e-23;
printf("%e, %f, %g", num, num, num);
```

prints out the following result:

```
1.000000e-023, 0.000000, 1e-023
```